# Finding Big O notation

Tags: big-o

I have the following code and I want to find the Big O. I wrote my answers as comments and would like to check my answers for each sentence and the final result.

```
public static void findBigO(int [] x, int n)
{ 
    //1 time
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) //n time
        x[i] += 2; //n+1 time

    int i = 1; //1 time
    while (i <= n/2) // n time
    { 
        x[i] += x[i+1]; // n+1 time
        i++; //n+1 time
    }
} //0

//result: 1 + n + n+1 + n + n+1 + n+1  = O(n)
```

Comment: Lovely that you use two seperate `i`s on two different rows. Also, this method is linear, `n/2` is the same as `n` when talking about Ordo. "For every n element you get a proportional increase in terms of executions.

Comment: I made some changes on the answer I think now it is correct right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: simple sums and increments are O(1), they are made in constant time so `x[i] += 2;` is constant since array indexing is also O(1) the same is true for `i++` and the like.

Second: The complexity of a function is relative to its input size, so in fact this function's time complexity is only [pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time)

Since n is an integer, the loop takes about n/2 interactions which is linear on the **value** of n but not on the **size** of n (4 bytes or log(n)).

So this algorithm is in fact exponential on the **size** of n.

Comment: that means x[i] += 2 is O(n+1)--->O(n)    and i++ =O(log n+1) --->O(log n)

Comment: Also the while loop is not O(logn) it is O(n/2) = O(n) so in fact you have a linear function O(n) on the value of n (but not on its size)

Comment: Try to read up on pseudo-polynomial functions, because while this function is indeed linear on the value of n its actually exponential on its size.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) // O(n)
    x[i] += 2;

int i = 1;
while (i <= n/2)               // O(n/2)
{ 
    x[i] += x[i+1];
    i++;
}
```

`O(n) + O(n/2) = O(n)` in terms of Big O.

You have to watch out for nested loops that depend on n, if (as I first thought thanks to double usage of `i`) you would've had that `O(n) * O(n/2)`, which is `O(n^2)`. In the first case it is in fact about `O(1,5n) + C` However that is never ever used to describe an Ordo.

With Big O you push the values towards infinity, no matter how large C you have it will in the end be obsolete, just as if it is `1.000.000n` or `n`. The prefix will eventually be obsolete.

That being said, the modifiers of `n` as well as the constants do matter, just not in Ordo context.